# Angular 6 Service worker refuses to cache assets as the ngsw.json is not fetched correctly

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

### Current behavior

i did `ng add @angular/pwa` and i have this error in production build

```
    Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
        at Driver.<anonymous> (ngsw-worker.js:2297)
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at fulfilled (ngsw-worker.js:1752)
```

[image: screenshot from 2018-07-12 16-13-32]
i did some research and found that there is issue with 
`/ngsw.json?ngsw-cache-bust=0.08769372894975769` GET request. though the fetchLatestManifest returns 200 status code,response is not actually JSON , instead its no script version of `index.html`

you can see response status is 200 for `/ngsw.json?ngsw-cache-bust=0.08769372894975769`
[image: screenshot from 2018-07-12 16-18-33]

but the actual response is not the required JSON
[image: screenshot from 2018-07-12 16-19-14]

i tried copy as fetch option in chrome 
Actual
```

```
fetch("https://officehawk.com/ngsw.json?ngsw-cache-bust=0.7927584506157848", {"credentials":"omit","headers":{},"referrer":"https://officehawk.com/ngsw-worker.js","referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade","body":null,"method":"GET","mode":"cors"});
```

```
and i removed `?ngsw-cache-bust=0.7927584506157848` from the URL part of fetch and i can see that the response is JSON.

Edited
```

```
fetch("https://officehawk.com/ngsw.json", {"credentials":"omit","headers":{},"referrer":"https://officehawk.com/ngsw-worker.js","referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade","body":null,"method":"GET","mode":"cors"});
```

```
so you can see the contents of ngsw.json now
[image: screenshot from 2018-07-12 16-35-24]

i suspect it has to be handled in this function ?
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/0b4d85e9f19246af68a75140afc4db3d97f9ddfd/packages/service-worker/worker/src/driver.ts#L645

### Environment

Angular version: 6.0.0

Browser:
- [x ] Chrome (desktop) version 67

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recently encountered this error on my Angular PWA using Nginx as my web/reverse proxy server.

I resolved my issue in my virtual server configuration for Nginx.  I changed my location block from this:

```
location / {
    root $root_path;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ index.html =404;

    error_page 404 =200 /index.html;
}
```

To this:

```
location / {
    root $root_path;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri$args $uri$args/ index.html =404;

    error_page 404 =200 /index.html;
}
```

The difference is on the try_files line. Basically this line tells Nginx how to check the path of the files being requested. They are evaluated in left to right order.

Comment: tats exactly what i did as well